# Spring integration - how to stop error propagation on the destination channel and avoid it to rollback the poller transaction?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a service using Spring Integration that fetches json arrays from the database (each array represents a transaction). Those json arrays are converted in database operations that must execute within a transaction on the destination (hence the `adviceChain` on the `@ServiceActivator`.

If the database operation any database operation fails, it must go to a "data hospital" where they'll be manually corrected.

When the transaction goes to the "data hospital", I want to avoid rolling back the poller transaction, so It wont' be fetched again.

How to stop the rolling back of the poller transaction in the scenario?

I also would probably to handle different exceptions where some of them would cause the rolling back of the poller transaction. For example, connection errors on the destination.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow(@Qualifier(PgSqlDataSourceConfig.PSQL_TRAN_MANAGER) final TransactionManager pgsqlTM) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(),
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(properties.getRateMs()).transactional(pgsqlTM)))
            .transform(controleGetJsDados())
            .channel(SybaseJsonSinkService.SYBASE_SINK)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sinkFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(SYBASE_SINK)
            .transform(jsonToDbOpTransformer())
            .channel(SYBASE_SINK_SQL)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public PublishSubscribeChannel errorChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(SYBASE_ERROR)
            .routeByException(r -> r.channelMapping(HospitalException.class, SYBASE_HOSPITAL)
                                    .channelMapping(Roman8Exception.class, SYBASE_SINK_ROMAN8)
                                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow())
            .get();
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = SYBASE_SINK_SQL, adviceChain = {TRAN_INTERCEPTOR})
public void sinkSql(final Message<DbTransaction> message) {
    try {
        //integrate to Database logic
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new HospitalException(message.getPayload(), ex);
    }
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = SYBASE_HOSPITAL)
public void sybaseHospital(final ErrorMessage errorMessage) {
    //puts data on a database hospital
}
```

Edit:

Tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(final TransactionManager tm) {
    RuleBasedTransactionAttribute rbta = new RuleBasedTransactionAttribute();
    List<RollbackRuleAttribute> rollbackRules = new ArrayList<>();
    rollbackRules.add(new NoRollbackRuleAttribute(Roman8Exception.class));
    rollbackRules.add(new NoRollbackRuleAttribute(HospitalException.class));
    rbta.setRollbackRules(rollbackRules);

    return new TransactionInterceptorBuilder(true)
            .transactionManager(tm)
            .isolation(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
            .propagation(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
            .transactionAttribute(rbta)
            .build();
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow(@Qualifier(PgSqlDataSourceConfig.PSQL_TRAN_MANAGER) final TransactionManager pgsqlTM) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(),
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(properties.getRateMs())
                                         .transactional(transactionInterceptor(pgsqlTM)).taskExecutor(executor())))
            .transform(controleGetJsDados())
            .channel(SybaseJsonSinkService.SYBASE_SINK)
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that in any case that data in DB must committed and not fetched again, then your `SYBASE_SINK` must be as an `ExecutorChannel`. In this case the data will go to the separate thread immediately after fetching and transaction will be committed. Any downstream error won't cause rollback and you are free to handle errors any way you'd like.

In this case you probably won't need a transaction configuration on the poller since all you do there in that thread is just data fetching.

It is not recommended to use a global `errorChannel` for handling business exception. You may consider to use any custom channel for error handling from downstream.

Comment: I learned some new things from your answer. I managed to create a custom error channel and the ExecutorChannel seems to work. But transactions never get created: https://gist.github.com/tsayao/608d2547dc2b21184626e6c11b58f977

Comment: Do you mean that `c.transactional(transactionInterceptor(tm))` doesn't have any effects? Then it has to be in a separate SO question with more context-specific info to let us isolate a culprit and probably reproduce on our side.